# Labels under inputs inline with other text

Tags: html, forms, css-tables

I need help aligning labels under input boxes such as a description of what should be input into the textbox, but I also need text aligned with the textbox after

I tried making new table rows below the input boxes and using margins, but this doesn't line up in Chrome, it does in IE, but not Chrome.

I've tried

< tr >< td colspan='1' >< span style='display: inline-block;' >You will arrive on: < input type='text' >
< label >(Date)< /label >at < input type='text' > 
 < label >(Time)< /label>< /span >, please bring all documents with you.

This should be:
You will arrive on:   at (inline with textboxes)  , please bring all documents with you.(align with previous text boxes, so this should be above the labels as well.)

Rephrasing:  I need something like a paragaph, with a block of text, but with inputs mixed into this text.  Then I need small descriptive labels directly under the inputs.  I don't want these small descriptive labels to be inline with the other paragraph's text only right under the inputs... example:
"This is a paragraph < input text here > < label that goes under input > paragraph text continues on here < another input text here > < label that goes under this input > again the paragraph text goes on here inline with the other paragraph text and the inputs"

Comment: Please, can you rephrase your question, is hard to understand what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've understood what you're trying to ask. You need to wrap the label and input in a div so that the label can be positioned off of the input tag.

```css
.label-under {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}

.label-under label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 10px;
}

span {
  line-height: 2.5;
}
```

```html
<span style='display: inline-block;' >You will arrive on: <div class="label-under"><input type='text' >
<label>(Date)</label></div> at <div class="label-under"><input type='text' >
<label>(Time)</label></div>, please bring all documents with you.</span>
```

Edit: You may need to adjust the line height of the span element if you're viewing on a device with a small width.

```
// Is optional and can be removed.
span {
  line-height: 2.5;
}
// But top: 10px must be changed to top: 20px
```

Answer (score 0):

skip the table and use display flex instead.

```css
.form {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.input-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

.input-container__label {
  margin-right: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<form action="" class="form">

  <div class="input-container">
    <label for="email" class="input-container__label">Email</label>
    <input type="text" class="input-container__element">
  </div>

  <div class="input-container">
    <label for="something" class="input-container__label">Something</label>
    <input type="text" class="input-container__element">
  </div>

</form>
```